# Android activity not starting on some devices (error inflating class)

Tags: android, resolution, sony, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

my program (actually not mine, I'm just trying to fix this bug) works fine on most phones, but it doesn't start on [Sony Xperia P](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_p-4436.php).

When I launch the program, the following message appears:

The application has stopped unexpectedly.

The app also doesn't have a launcher icon on this phone (only default icon).

The error log says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start Activity
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: error inflating class android.view.ImageView
```

The error message came up when the app called:

```
setContentView(R.layout.menu_0_splash);
```

I noticed that the drawable resources are defined for the following resolutions:

1024x600
320x240
400x240
480x320
800x480
854x480

This phone is 960x540, so my best quess is that there sould be dafault resources too.

What could be the problem?

The layout file (now copy/paste-d):

```
<?xml version       = "1.0" 
encoding    = "utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/m0_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_green" >

<ImageView #this is the problematic line
    android:id="@+id/arrow_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/m0_arrow_top_margintop"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_arrow_top" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/m0_arrow_bottom_marginbottom"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_arrow_bottom" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/belt_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_belt_top" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/belt_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_belt_bottom" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/t_ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/t_ad" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t_ad"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I realized what was wrong... The phone has a special resolution (960x540), and it cannot find source images for ImageView-s and dimension file for this resolution - that's why was the app running on other phones, as they use "common" resolution.

Thanks for the help, I appreciate it with a +1

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you actually copied/pasted the error from the log, then you have a typo:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start Activity
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: error
>   inflating class android.view.ImageVeiw

`ImageView` is spelled incorrectly in one of your layout.xml files.

Comment: Yes for the eagle eye, but no for the paste oparation. Somehow I wrote it wrong, sorry for that - I will edit it. But then It souldn't work on any phones, but it doesn't work only on the specified phone instead.

Comment: If that's the case, please post your layout.xml that you are trying to inflate.